# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030:

Tags: paypal, wsdl, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to paypal express checkout i used https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl. 
when i call use

```
PayPalAPIAASoapBinding paypal = new PayPalAPIAASoapBinding();
```

i am getting error

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: 
>   Cannot convert type
>   'exprtesscheckoutdemo.com.paypal.sandbox.TupleType[]' to
>   'paypal.sandbox.TupleType' error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert
>   type 'paypal.sandbox.TupleType' to

how to over come this

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just hit this myself when updating to version 119. In your generated Web service file, do a find for `[][]` and replace all occurrences with `[]`. The bad guy seems to be the `merchantDataField` in the `PaymentDetailsType`.

[It seems to be a bug in the Microsoft WSDL tools](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2010/07/wcf-client-proxy-deserialization-issue.html) when interacting with services that have "nested nodes with the maxOccurs attribute set to unbounded"; I've encountered it before when interacting with FedEx SOAP APIs as well.

Comment: I hit this problem too.  Your fix solved the problem.  Many thanks!

I would be curious to find out solution for vb.net.  I implemented your fix in the context of a C# class library, which I then compiled then added to my VB project.

Comment: Also thanks. This is the 2nd fix I had to do to the PayPal generated Reference.cs file. The other had to do with a deserialize trap - Namespace 'cc' and 'ebl' not defined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172197/paypal-setexpresscheckout-soap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106242/paypal-soap-api-reponses-require-manual-parsing .

Comment: This works very nicely and still an issue when updating to PP API v204. I'm in contact with PayPal as we're updating from v84 and they had no idea about this. Thanks, this is a top answer! @brando I just did this in VB.net, it's the same process, but instead of [][] look for ()() < VB array notation.

Comment: Had this issue with Salesforce soap WSDL as well.

Comment: I just logged here to upvote this solution because it worked very well.